# Having trouble with iteration and assigning with tkinter in python

Tags: python

Im designing a **Mastermind** game, and so far have come up with a circle that changes color with iterating through a list of colors with the press of a button:

```
set_up_answer = []

color_iteration1 = itertools.cycle(('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red','yellow'))

def callback1():
    mcircle1 = mycanvas.create_oval(10,620,86,675,outline='#000000',fill=next(color_iteration1))
    res1 = mycanvas.itemcget(mcircle1, 'fill')
    set_up_answer.append(res1)

B1 = Button(root,text='B1',command =callback1)
```

Keep in mind this is not complete code***, and what happens is that if i go through the iterate list by pressing the button multiple times, end up with say the circle containing the fill 'orange' and then add it to (set_up_answer) to compare to other circles, what it returns is something like ['blue', 'green',  'orange'], meaning it returns every color in the iterate list before what the actual fill is as well as the actual fill color, how do I limit the value returning the fill to just the specific color of the iterate list it actually is?

Comment: Are you wanting `set_up_answer` to only have one value? Are you using a list as a global so that you can modify it within the function? You could just have `global set_up_answer` in the function , then you can assign to it. This isn't ideal, but will work.

Comment: Peter, no I am using a list because I am planning to add multiple more circles, in which each will add their fill color to create a list(set_up_answer) of a set of different colors, to then be compared to an answer key(different list) that has randomly generated colors, and if they are the same to return true.

Comment: Each time you press the button it appends the colour to the list. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def callback1():
    color = next(color_iteration1)
    mcircle1 = mycanvas.create_oval(10,620,86,675,outline='#000000',fill=color)
    set_up_answer.append(color)
```

Using `mycanvas.itemcget` seems very roundabout and might be the cause of your problem (I don't know tkinter so I can't tell).